# Requirements for Mayer-Vietoris

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This question might be a duplicate -- but as I don't find an entry (maybe because of the lack of a good keyword) I open this question.
Besides, this questions arises when trying to prove Proposition 2B.1. (a) in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology".

### Terminology

Here: $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is the unit interval and $S^n$ is the $n$-th unit sphere.

Let $h_k : I^k \to S^n$ be any embedding (i.e. a map that is a homeomorphism onto its image). We define:

$$S([a,b]) = S^n - h_k(I^{k-1}\times[a,b])$$

for $a,b\in I$ with $a \leq b$.

### The question

Say $A = S([a,c]), B = S([c,b])$. I want to apply the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence onto $A \cup B$. This means I have to show either

> $A \cup B = A^° \cup B^°$

or:

> $A,B$ are deformation retracts of neighborhoods $U,V$ with $U \cap V$ deformation retracting onto $A\cap B$. (As far as I can see, here "deformation retract" means [strong deformation retract](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongDeformationRetract.html).)

How to show at least one of them?

### Own ideas

We have that $I^{k-1}\times[a,b]$ is closed in $I^k$. If we would have that $h_k$ is closed, then of course, $A$ would be open. But it needn't. So one way to continue the investigation would be: how would an non-closed embedding $I^k \to S^n$ look like?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every embedding $I^k\hookrightarrow S^n$ is indeed closed. Since $I^k$ is a compact space, its image $h(I^k)$ is also compact and hence closed in $S^n$. Now $S^n$ is Hausdorff and [compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are closed](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Subspace_of_Hausdorff_Space_is_Closed). Thus, $A$ and $B$ are open subsets of $S^n$ and you can apply Mayer-Vietoris on $A\cup B$.

Comment: Thank you for your effort.  : )